Mounted targets interaction with spells
I'm looking for information on how spells interact with/affect mounted targets. Examples I'm most interested in (since I suspect it might vary between spells):

Invisibility. Are mounted target treated as single target together with his mount or does it require 2 spells? I see a potential loophole if it's 2 spells because being mounted is a constant interaction so it would break Invisibility potentially?
Resilient Sphere. Will it trap rider and mount together or will it force-eject rider, potentially making him fall a long way in case of flying mount being targeted.


More on the spell resilient sphere.

The rider is a separate creature
The mounted combat rules contain nothing that indicates that rider and mount would count as a single target for spells.
So these are two separate creatures. If you target the rider with invisibility or some other effect, normally the mount is unaffected. If you cast resilent sphere on the rider and it succeeds, only the rider will be enclosed.
The rider and the mount share a space however, so area effect spells of course will affect both.
(Maybe you remember some rule from the D&D 5e spell find steed, which says: "While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed."? Mounted combat in PF1 has no such rule, but PF1 has a Improved Share Spells option that says

Any non-instantaneous spell (but not any spell-like ability) you cast on yourself can also affect a creature bonded to you (such as an animal companion, eidolon, familiar, or special mount

Not quite the same, as it does not work for spells cast by others. Thanks to @KRyan for pointing to this.)

If the mount is special, and the spell is cast by the rider, share spells might be relevant; it’s not truly counting them as a single target, but they could both be affected by a spell that would otherwise target only one of them. Also, the way in which the mount and rider share the same space might be the source of the confusion, and is probably worth going into.

@KRyan Both good suggestions, thank you.

You refer to Improved Share Spells, and that is indeed the feat you want, but you link to regular Share Spells. (I forgot Pathfinder moved that ability into feats; 3.5e just has it as a default part of those sorts of companions.)

Ar, copy and paste SNAFU. Fixed, thank you.
